# I want to know sharding way on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharding

I want to realize sharding (horizontal partition of table), and I am using SQL Server Standard edition. I don't have any knowledge.

I searched : mysql can use sharding platform. U think dbms can support this.

But I didn't find any article about SQL Server.

Do I have to develop sharding on source code level? Or do I use any function on SQL Server?

Please give to me idea!

Thanks

I am using SQL Server 2017 Standard edition.

Comment: MSSQL does not natively support sharding.  You can add it at the application level.

Comment: In MSSQL this is called "Federated Partitioned VIews" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266260/sql-server-table-partitioning-can-i-distribute-tables-across-servers

Comment: You can even "shard" a table between an on-premise Sql Server and an Azure Sql instance. But Sql Server -- and the associated community of people writing things like blog posts and documentation -- don't call it sharding.

Comment: Also, I don't think as many people do "horizontal partitioning of tables" anymore in Sql Server. Availability Groups (which include readable secondaries) are the new better way to accomplish similar scalability.

Comment: Why do you think you need sharding?

Comment: Aside from Availability Groups, newer systems also tend to look at caching technologies like Hadoop for scaling long before they look at sharding. Also, servers have gotten bigger and better. You're usually running a top 100 global web site before you're too big to fit on a single server. Sharding is really kind of old tech now... which fits the MySql reference in the question, as MySql spent almost 10 years starting just before the Oracle acquisition without really advancing much.

Answer (score 4):

You can create horizontal partitioning in SQL Server using  [Partitioned Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#partitioned-views)  or table partitioning [table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes)

Microsoft doesn't use the term sharding, but the end result is the same